# Buffereader to inputstream still having corruption

Tags: java, sockets

We have java socket connection application which receives data from gps devices. The problem now at times we received corrupted data and checked on the device logs everything is fine. First BufferedReader was used and suspected to be the culprit. The we moved to inpustream also still having problem. The corruption is at random and not fixed interval. Below is the snippet of codes.

```
public void run() { 

     String completeMessage="";
     //BufferedReader readerBuffer = null; 
     InputStream is = null;    
     BufferedWriter writeBuffer = null;

     try {
         //readerBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockConn1.getInputStream()));
         is = sockConn1.getInputStream();
         writeBuffer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sockConn1.getOutputStream()));

         int readChar=0;         

         sockConn1.setSoTimeout(120000);
         //dbConnection = connectionPool.getConnection();
         //dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
           int readChar
            while ((readChar=is.read()) != -1) 
             {                

                 System.out.println("Char value: "+(char)readChar) ;
                  if (readChar == '*') {
                   try {

                     //writeBuffer.write("@@\r\n\r\n");
                     //writeBuffer.flush();                 
                     //db processing
                    dbConnection.commit();
                   }
                   catch (SQLException ex){ 
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                            try{    
                            dbConnection.rollback();  
                            } 
                            catch (Exception rollback){    
                                rollback.printStackTrace();
                            }
                  }
                  catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                            try{    
                            dbConnection.rollback();  
                            } 
                            catch (Exception rollback){    
                                rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
                            }
                  }
                  finally{
                        try{
                            if ( dbStmt != null ){
                              dbStmt.close();
                            }                           
                        }
                        catch(SQLException ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                        }                      
                      }      
                completeMessage="";           
                }

             }
          }
          catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){ 
               ex.printStackTrace();
          }  
          catch (IOException ex){ 
               ex.printStackTrace();
          }  
          catch (Exception ex){ 
               ex.printStackTrace();
          }      
          finally{
            try{
                if ( dbConnection != null ){
                  dbConnection.close();
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                if ( writeBuffer != null ){
                    writeBuffer.close();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
               ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }           
          }

      }
```

Comment: Is the communication *meant* to be binary or text? You've posted a lot of code, most of which seems to have little to do with the socket connection and a lot to do with the database handling (including some worrying "catch Exception" clauses).

Comment: @jon the communication is send from the devices is in byte form. So what chance you suggest here?

Comment: You do conversion from bytes to characters and therefore you must know the encoding or you cannot proper decode the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem. You read/write binary data as text:

- InputStream, OutputStream = binary data
- Reader, Writer = text

This is bridged by:

- new InputStremReader(inputStream, charEncoding)
- new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charEncoding)

And String to byte is bridged by:

- new String(bytes, charEncoding)
- string.getBygtes(charEncoding)

Where charEncoding is an optional parameter, defaulting to the operation system encoding.

With UTF-8, the Unicode multi-byte encoding, you are fast into troubles if done wrong. Also other encodings have problematic bytes.

So do not use Reader/Writer.

The `read()` delivers an int, -1 for end-of-file, a byte value otherwise.
It seems your test with read() throws a byte away, and the subsequent read does not test for -1.

Comment: I am a bit confuse. What should I change to the read() then? Should I make it like this now InputStreamReader isr = null;    InputStream is = null;is = sockConn1.getInputStream();isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "ASCII"); ? IS this correct ?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was intended to start commenting on your correct decision not to use Reader/Writer but a telephone call interrupted and takes my time now and I have made a mess of my answer. Ignore the last part; in 5 minutes I will delete the answer. You are not doing anything inherently wrong, but db code could be more encapsulated, so exception handling is easier to see through.

Comment: I ok joop no problem with your phone call. What you think based on your experience could corrupt it?

Comment: I might have done the communication as isolated and separate as possible. There is not much to see from the socket code. If you are in a JEE container, sharing/persistency is an issue (a socket should not be a servlet field for instance). Maybe a concurrency issue? Logging needed.

Comment: no is not in a JEE container. Is individual itself. So could it be due to some socket errors? What to check for?SHould I do some packet analysis?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what character encoding is used here.

When you deal with character streams then it is nearly always a good idea to explicitly provide the character encoding to en-/decode the byte stream.

In my opinion it is most likely a character encoding issue here. Use the same encoding on both sides and you won't have trouble with Reader/Writer.

Comment: tried "US-ASCII" both also the same too. What else could go wrong?

Comment: Tried "US-ASCII" for encoding _and_ decoding on _both_ sides? You still not provide a character encoding in your Writer. This is at least error-prone when not really a bug. Proper use cases for OutputStreamWriter's one-arg constructor are rare. Use one where you have to provide the character encoding.

Comment: is this ok new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sockConn1.getOutputStream(),"US-ASCII"));

Comment: Yes, and the same for the InputStreamReader. Use explicit character encoding here, too. And after that ensure to do it on both sides of your communication.

Comment: I have confirm the device is using US-ASCII and for the reader this how I am doing InputStreamReader isr = null; InputStream is = null;is = sockConn1.getInputStream();isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "ASCII");

Comment: Looks ok except for the character encoding identifier which must be `"US-ASCII"` and not `"ASCII"`. When you use Guava Lib then you may want to use constants in `com.google.common.base.Charsets`. I am not really sure but I think Java 7 now provide something similar.

Comment: Yes I have put US-ASCII in both the reader and writer. Let me test and update you guys ok. Hope it works now. But is very intermittent you know is not a permanent problem for all the data. Do you strongly believe is due to encoding?

Comment: Since many charsets are subsets of others it is very likely that problems only occur under certain circumstances, i.e. special characters used. You're improving code stability for sure and I still believe there is a good chance to solve your problems.

Comment: unfortunately is still the same problem is being corrupted again.

Comment: Then you've to provide more detail about how it is "corrupted". And what data you'd expect.

Comment: It is very unlikely that any Reader/Writer class is the culprid because it is widely used without problems. In fact wrong usage of them is more likely to be the culprid.

Comment: Based on my codes what do you suspect could be the culprit? I dont think so the db got anything to do with the socket rite. Should like clear my sockets? I notice if I put double of this \r\n then it reduces the corruption this leading to some where?